# How to duplicate file.jpg 1000 times at once in python?

Tags: python, shutil

I want to duplicate file 1000 times at once so I tried this code to create a file duplicator, but it only duplicates 1 file in the directory.

```
import shutil

src = r'D:\src\file.jpg'
dst = r'D:\dst\file.jpg'

for _ in range(5):
    shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

Comment: Change the name of the destination file to avoid overwriting the same file over and over

Comment: In your own words, how many files named `file.jpg` do you expect to be able to put into the same folder? In your own words, if you want to put 1000 copies of a file into a folder, how should you name the copies in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, You want to duplicate the file `n` times, which is equal to `5` in your given code.

**Firstly** There is no need to declare two variables with same value if you do not intend to change it later, so:

```
import shutil

src = r'D:\src\file.jpg'
ext = r'.jpg'

#Change the 5 to what number you want to duplicate
for i in range(5):
    shutil.copy(src, f'{src + str(i) + ext}')
```

I changed the code so that the file name will be different with the increasing file count.

**EX:**

```
file0.jpg
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
...
```

**Edit:** Thanks Timus for reminding me, I changed `i` to `str(i)` since `i` is an integer originally and you can't add it to the end of a string.

Comment: Will that `f'{src + i + ext}'` work?

Comment: @Timus thanks for the heads up, I totally forgot that the i was an integer :D